# Marketo REST API Get Multiple Leads By List Id

Tags: marketo

Will the REST API get leads from a Smartlist?  I created a Smartlist and it has one lead.  I sent in this API call:

https://.........../rest/v1/list/{DeanReadyToMove}/leads.json?access_token=..............

and got zero leads back.  'DeanReadyToMove' is the list name and the API call seems to talk about reading by list ID but I can't figure out where to get the list ID from if in fact the list name is the wrong thing.  Also tried taking the braces out of the API call but no difference.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to query leads from a smart list in Marketo. You can query leads from a static list.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Bulk Download API will let you input a Smart List or a Static List, and retrieve all the leads included in either type of list.

Here is the documentation for reference:
http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/bulk-lead-extract/

Comment: Is this _really_ link only? The link is an end point which the OP can use instead of their current end point. Had the link not be there _The latest Bulk Download API will let you input a Smart List or a Static List_ would be an attempt to answer.